# Which view touch event will get called + iPhone

Tags: iphone

**First Scenario** :
Suppose we have a first view as FirstView. in this view(FirstView) we add another view(SecondView) having exactly same frame as FirstView as

```
[FirstView addSubView:SecondView];
```

Now touch event of which view(FirstView or SecondView) will get called?

**Second Scenario** :

suppose after adding SecondView(frame exactly same as FirstView) to FirstView I write 
[FirstView:sendSubView];

Now touch event of which view will get invoked?

Answer (score 1):

First Scenario:

If the second view can receive user actions(that is user interaction enabled) then second view's touch events gets called.

Second Scenario:

I believe the function you were mentioning is sendSubViewToBack. In this case, if no other subviews were added to the firstview, it is equivalent to first scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Also see this:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/EventsiPhoneOS/EventsiPhoneOS.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW5